# Segmentation fault using calloc() in C

Tags: c, bitmap, malloc, calloc

I've ran into a bit of a pickle when using **malloc** or **calloc**. I keep getting a **seg fault**, 
 I tested for it's allocation of memory, I free the memory afterwards.

The program is an exercise in resizing an BMP image. I've been able to successfully copy the headers into a new file and to resize the desired image horizontally. When I get to the code that is meant to resize it vertically I run into problems.

I've ran the debugger and it stops after the 2nd loop due to a seg fault. I've put the calloc inside the second loop along with the free call, I've allocated a smaller chunk of memory and got the read and write functions to do similarly, but that doesn't change anything. I still keep getting a seg fault.

Here's the problematic code:

```
    // dynamic memory allocation for pixels
    // RGBTRIPLE is a typedef struct made up of three 1 byte members
    RGBTRIPLE *resizePixel; 

    //resize is the factor to resize the image by
    resizePixel = calloc(resize, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE)); 
    if (resizePixel == NULL) 
    {
        printf("Horsefeathers!  We're probably out of memory!\n");
        return 5;
    }


    // loop to create vertical resizing
    for (int m = 0; m < biHeight - 1; ++m)
    {

        for (int n = 0; n < bi.biWidth; ++n)
        {

            // reposition pointer to start of row in preparation for copying
            fseek(outptr, -(tempBi.biWidth + resizePad), SEEK_CUR);

            // read from outptr file resize-number of pixels
            fread(&resizePixel, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), resize, outptr);

            // reposition file pointer to end of file
            fseek(outptr, 0, SEEK_END);

            // write to outptr file resize-number of pixels
            fwrite(&resizePixel, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), resize, outptr);

        }

        // release dynamic memory
        free(resizePixel);   

        // adds padding to resized image
        if (resizePad > 0)
            for (int k = 0; k < resizePad; k++)
                fputc(0x00, outptr);

    }
}
```

Let me know if anyone requires more info.

Comment: Why do you spam C++ tag?

Comment: `fread(&resizePixel, ...);` This doesn't read into memory pointed to by `resizePixel`. This overwrites the 4 or 8 bytes that `resizePixel` pointer itself occupies, then proceeds to trash whatever's in memory above it. Drop the ampersand. Similarly with `fwrite` call.

Comment: Thanks Igor, that worked!